# how to animate uitoolbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitabbar, uitoolbar

I am trying to animate my uitoolbar. I am trying to expand and contract my uiview. i want the toolbar to animated along with the view. But here the uitoolbar expands and contracts first then the uiview is animating. So the uitoolbar frame is changing according to the rect but its not animating. can somebody please tell me if how to animate uitoolbar. Along with the toolbar i also want to animate the tabbar. how should i go about doing this.

In my view i have written the following code :

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(void){

        [recordDetailView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, recordDetailView.frame.size.height)];
        [normalModeToolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,self.view.frame.size.width, 49)];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:recordDetailView];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
    }
     ];
```

Answer (score 1):

*UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews* (iOS > 4.0) should fix the problem when the size change is not being animated.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
        delay:0 
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews 
        animations:^{
           [recordDetailView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width,                 recordDetailView.frame.size.height)];
           [normalModeToolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,self.view.frame.size.width, 49)];
       }
        completion:nil
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use bounds instead?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(void){
    yourView.bounds = CGRectMake(yourView.bounds.origin.x, 
                                 yourView.bounds.origin.y, 
                                 yourView.bounds.size.width * 2, // target width 
                                 yourView.bounds.size.height);
}];
```

Furthermore I would also try bringing your `recordDetailView` to front before starting the animation.

Comment: frame is animatable. You are confused with CALayer and UIView classes.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that hint! How do I find out about animatable properties of UIView, then?

Comment: [What Can Be Animated?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW2)

Comment: @zlajo :  my view is animating properly. but i want to animate the toolbar. the toolbar changes its frame but doesnt animate. Can u tell me why the toolbar might not be animating????